# Is the word 'profile' an in build feature in Django?

Tags: django, django-signals

I am a newbie to Django. Below code is to create a user profile when new user signup for my Blog application.

Doubt : - Why do we use profile instead of Profile in the last code line ?
please note the capitalized word 'Profile'

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Profile


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, *args,**kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, *args,**kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()'''  #last code line
```

Comment: No, it is not a builtin feature, Django creates a relation with the name of the model in *lowercase* with underscore as word separators, this is according to PEP-8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**, it is not a builtin feature. If you define a relation from your model (for example `Profile` to `User`), Django automatically creates a reverse relation. You can specify the name of that relation with the `related_name` attribute.

You can thus specify the name differently by altering the [**`related_name`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) of the relation, for example:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='other_attribute'
    )
```

In that case the name of the profile is:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

@receiver(post_save, sender=get_user_model())
def save_profile(sender, instance, *args,**kwargs):
    instance.other_attribute.save()
```

By default the `related_name` value is the name of the class, but in *lowercase*, and with underscores (`_`) as word separator.

This is according to [**PEP-8**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) where attributes of a class are written in lowercase and with underscores as word separator.

Answer (score 2):

I think in your code 
**Profile** is name of Model :

```
Class Profile(models.Model)
```

and **profile** is related_name of reverse relation like:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
user= models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="profile")
```

when you want use all objects of model Use:

```
Profile.objects.all()
```

and when you want user objects :

```
userobject.profile.<other fields name>
```